# FTL : How to check whether a value in string type contains number or characters

Tags: freemarker

Issue :
I am getting a value from a list.
List contains a string values.
I need to check whether that value of list contains a character value or only digits.

```
<#assign arr =["0-200000", "200001-500000" ,"500001 & above"]/>
<#list arr as prcVal>
    <#assign vals= prcVal?split('-')/>  
    <#assign rangeStart = ""/>
        <#assign arrIndex = 0/>
    <#list vals as prcVal1>
        <#if prcVal1?index_of("& above") gt 0>
            <#assign prcVal2 = (prcVal1?split('&')[0])?trim/>
            <#if prcVal2?number gt 99>
                <#assign rangeStart = prcVal2?number?string[",000"] + ' &' + prcVal1?split('&')[1]/>
            </#if>
        <#else>
            <#if prcVal1?number gt 99>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart  + prcVal1?number?string[",000"]/>
            <#else>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart  + prcVal1/>
            </#if>
            <#if arrIndex == 0>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart + '-'/>
            </#if>
            <#assign arrIndex = arrIndex + 1/>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    ${rangeStart}
</#list>
```

Inside list if prcVal1 has '&' it goes under that condition else under "else" condition.

if prcVal1  doesnot contains '&' it goes to "else", but under that i checked "`#if prcVal1?number gt 99`" because of prcVal1 contains characters it cannot be converted to number, i'l be getting FTL error.

```
id?is_number or ?is_string
```

these inbuild conditions i got, but this checks tyoe of a value only.
Eg : `prcVal1="100"` contains digits, but `prcVal1?is_number` returns false.

```
<#assign arr =["0-200000", "200001-500000" ,"500001 & above","test"]/>
<#list arr as prcVal>
    <#assign vals= prcVal?split('-')/>  
    <#assign rangeStart = ""/>
         <#assign arrIndex = 0/>
    <#list vals as prcVal1>
        <#if prcVal1?index_of("& above") gt 0>
            <#assign prcVal2 = (prcVal1?split('&')[0])?trim/>
            <#if prcVal2?number gt 99>
                <#assign rangeStart = prcVal2?number?string[",000"] + ' &' + prcVal1?split('&')[1]/>
            </#if>
        <#else>
            <#if prcVal1?number gt 99>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart  + prcVal1?number?string[",000"]/>
            <#else>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart  + prcVal1/>
            </#if>
            <#if arrIndex == 0>
                <#assign rangeStart = rangeStart + '-'/>
            </#if>
            <#assign arrIndex = arrIndex + 1/>
        </#if>
    </#list>
    ${rangeStart}
</#list>
```

Above code throws error because of test in input, i need to check and skip that.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to check whether a value has string values or digits.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (2.3.28) you have to use a regular expressions. This will evaluate to `true` or `false` depending on if `pcVal` is a whole number (optionally with a `-` or `+` prefix): `pcVal?matches(r'[-\+]?[0-9]+')`. Note that it doesn't match decimals (like `1.5`) though, but I guess you can extend the regular expression further from here if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Freemarker's [builtin replace](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace) which will remove other characters than number, for example in your case this can fit

```
<#assign prcVal1 = prcVal1?replace("[a-zA-Z& ]+", "", "r") />
```

Or replace all not numbers characters using `\D`:

```
<#assign prcVal1 = prcVal1?replace("[\\D]+", "", "r") />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please tell how to check whether prcVal1  contains a string rather than replacing it.

Comment: But if you want only numbers, you can assign to new variable and check the new variable `?number`

Comment: sorry this is not working. ?number converts to number, wont check. If prcVal1 ="test", prcVal1 ?number throws error

Comment: The second option will strip decimals.
100.01 will become 10001, careful!